# How to get Postfix to work with Dovecot using an LMTP inet_listener and SSL?

Tags: ssl, postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to get Postfix 3.4.13 to deliver mail to a remote Dovecot 2.3.7.2 instance using an LMTP inet_listener with SSL turned on. LMTP works fine without SSL enabled, and other Dovecot protocols work fine with the same self-signed SSL certificate. LMTP with an inet_listener and SSL isn't, with Postfix giving a:

```
"lost connection with 192.168.1.105[192.168.1.105] while receiving the initial server greeting"
```

error and this from Dovecot:

```
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Connect from 192.168.1.115
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x10, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: before SSL initialization
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: before SSL initialization
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read client hello
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write server hello
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write certificate
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write finished
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: message repeated 4 times: [ lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=-1: TLSv1.3 early data]
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: TLSv1.3 early data
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS read finished
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x20, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2001, ret=1: SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
Feb 28 18:34:05 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL: where=0x2002, ret=1: SSL negotiation finished successfully
Feb 28 18:35:18 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL error: Connection closed
Feb 28 18:35:18 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Debug: SSL alert: close notify
Feb 28 18:35:18 curly dovecot: lmtp(360396): Disconnect from 192.168.1.115: Remote closed connection (state=READY)
```

Does anyone have this configuration running and successfully using SSL without relying on an additional package like Stunnel? Can you share the revelant parts of your Postfix master.cf, main.cf and Dovecot configuration please?

Comment: I suspect you are missing an explanatory log line right before both side noting about the connection closing. Do note that `smtp_tls_loglevel` and `lmtp_tls_loglevel` can be configured separately in postfix.